# How do i stop error message from the while statement if the condition for the if statement is met?

Tags: python, database, input, while-loop

Hello I have a problem with my code and I am not sure what the fix is, the code is supposed to supposed to print shadow identified and print the required information when the input is right, and print the error message when the input is incorrect and ask for the name of shadow again however when the input is correct it prints the error message along with the shadow identified message and required information.

```
import time

print("Hello, welcome to the Persona 5 Helper")
time.sleep(2)
print("Type in the name of the shadow you're facing and the app will show you its weaknesses\n")
time.sleep(2)

shadows = {"Crypt-dwelling Demon": "Jack-O lantern\n" "Version P5: Inherit = Fire, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = Fire, Block = N\A, Resists = N\A, Weak = Gun/Ice/Wind\n"
                                   "Version P5R: Inherit = N\A, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = Fire, Block = N\A, Resists = N\A, Weak = Ice/Wind",
           "Beguiling Girl": "Pixie\n" "Version Both: Inherit = Elec, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = N\A, Block = N\A, Resists = Elec/Bless, Weak = Gun/Ice/Curse",
           "Bedside Brute": "Incubus\n" "Version Both: Inherit = Ailment, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = N\A, Block = N\A, Resists = Elec, Weak = Gun/Bless",
           "Gallows Flower": "Mandrake\n" "Version Both: Inherit = Elec, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = N\A, Block = N\A, Resists = Elec/Bless, Weak = Wind",
           "Dirty Two-horned Beast": "Bicorn\n" "Version Both: Inherit = Wind, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = N\A, Block = N\A, Resists = Curse, Weak = Elec",
           "Apprentice in a jug": "Agathion\n" "Version Both: Inherit = Elec, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = N\A, Block = N\A, Resists = Elec/Gun, Weak = Wind"}

shadowName = ""

while shadowName not in shadows:
    shadowName = input("Name of shadow: ")
    print('ERROR: Make sure your spelling is correct or the shadow is an existing one...')

if shadowName in shadows:
    print("Shadow Identified...")
    print(shadows[shadowName])
```

Comment: In the while loop you print the error message right after you input the name, regardless of whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your code, shadowName is initialized with "".

Since "" is not in shadows (while condition), your program will ask for the "Name of shadow" (input) and regardless of your input, it will always print this first error message.

You can't change these two lines inside the for loop because for the first name the error message will still appear.

A solution is: instead of initializing shadowName with "", ask for the input.

Also, change the line order so the error message will appear before the input asking. And you don't need the if condition, since if not (shadowName in shadows) (ie the if condition is False), then the program will be trapped inside the while loop anyway:

```
shadowName = input("Name of shadow: ")

while shadowName not in shadows:
    print('ERROR: Make sure your spelling is correct or the shadow is an existing one...')
    shadowName = input("Name of shadow: ")

print("Shadow Identified...")
print(shadows[shadowName])
```

Comment: Hello Daquisu I edited my code like you said and asking for input is definitely a better way of doing it, thanks for helping me out and thanks for also explaining why my code didnt work!!!

Answer (score 0):

The print function was executed immediately after the input, so it shows an error. Try this.

```
import time

print("Hello, welcome to the Persona 5 Helper")
time.sleep(2)
print("Type in the name of the shadow you're facing and the app will show you its weaknesses\n")
time.sleep(2)

shadows = {"Crypt-dwelling Demon": "Jack-O lantern\n" "Version P5: Inherit = Fire, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = Fire, Block = N\A, Resists = N\A, Weak = Gun/Ice/Wind\n"
                                   "Version P5R: Inherit = N\A, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = Fire, Block = N\A, Resists = N\A, Weak = Ice/Wind",
           "Beguiling Girl": "Pixie\n" "Version Both: Inherit = Elec, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = N\A, Block = N\A, Resists = Elec/Bless, Weak = Gun/Ice/Curse",
           "Bedside Brute": "Incubus\n" "Version Both: Inherit = Ailment, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = N\A, Block = N\A, Resists = Elec, Weak = Gun/Bless",
           "Gallows Flower": "Mandrake\n" "Version Both: Inherit = Elec, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = N\A, Block = N\A, Resists = Elec/Bless, Weak = Wind",
           "Dirty Two-horned Beast": "Bicorn\n" "Version Both: Inherit = Wind, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = N\A, Block = N\A, Resists = Curse, Weak = Elec",
           "Apprentice in a jug": "Agathion\n" "Version Both: Inherit = Elec, Reflects = N\A, Absorbs = N\A, Block = N\A, Resists = Elec/Gun, Weak = Wind"}

shadowName = ""

while shadowName not in shadows:
    shadowName = input("Name of shadow: ")
    
    if shadowName in shadows:
        print("Shadow Identified...")
        print(shadows[shadowName])
        break
    else:
        print('ERROR: Make sure your spelling is correct or the shadow is an existing one...')
```

Comment: Hello Sujay, I actually tried doing something similar at first by putting an if and else statement inside the while loop but the print statement for the else would print infinitely, I see that this is the proper way to do it. Thank for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would rearrange your while loop a little:

```py
while True:
    shadowName = input("Name of shadow: ")
    
    if shadowName in shadows:
        break
    
    print('ERROR: Make sure your spelling is correct or the shadow is an existing one...')
```

Comment: Hi Seb I edited my code like how you suggested and it fixed my problem, thanks a lot for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the code like this.

```
while shadowName not in shadows:
    shadowName = input("Name of shadow: ")
    if shadowName in shadows:
        print("Shadow Identified...")
        print(shadows[shadowName])
    else:
        print('ERROR: Make sure your spelling is correct or the shadow is an existing one...')
```

Comment: Hello Eriq I edited my code like how you said and it worked as I wanted it to, thanks a lot for helping!!!

Comment: Don't mention it, my friend!